# How run composer install from dockerfile in php container

Tags: php, docker

Good day I have php container which seting up in Dockerfile

I am trying to run composer install with this command

```
WORKDIR '/app'
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
            php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
        CMD bash -c "composer install && php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80"
    EXPOSE 80
    EXPOSE 22
    CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

But I didnt get the error, and can not run application because of the composer install didnt worked.Just white screen of laravel which mean composer was not installed.

If I run after docker compose up

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/app composer/composer install
```

I receive an error
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /app
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

If I trying to COPY project dirrectory I receive an error

```
COPY /var/www/docker/project /app
```

ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder091462376/var/www/docker/project: no such file or directory
While I have the volumes in php container in docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
            - /app/vendor/
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
     image: nginx:latest
     container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx"
     environment:
       NGINX_STATIC_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
       NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
       NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
       NGINX_VHOST_PRESET: php
       NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /app/public
     ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
     volumes:
        - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
        - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
     links:
        - php

     labels:
       - 'traefik.backend=nginx'
       - 'traefik.port=80'
       - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'  
    php:
        build: ./images/php
        links:
            - mariadb
        #command: bash -c 'cd /app composer install'    
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
            - /app/vendor/

    mariadb:
     image: wodby/mariadb:$MARIADB_TAG
     container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mariadb"
     stop_grace_period: 30s
     environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD

    pma:
     image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
     container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_pma"
     ports:
        - "9000:80"
     environment:
       PMA_HOST: $DB_HOST
       PMA_USER: $DB_USER
       PMA_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
       PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 1G
       PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS: 1G
     labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=pma'
      - 'traefik.port=80'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:pma.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'
```

Here is completely Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine3.6
WORKDIR '/app'
RUN apk update && apk upgrade\
    && apk add --no-cache curl libbz2 php7-bz2 php7-pdo php7-pgsql php7-bcmath php7-zmq php7-curl bash php7-pear php7-imagick openssh imap-dev\
    libtool \
    postgresql-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    imagemagick-c++ \
    imagemagick-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    yaml-dev \
    bzip2 \
    aspell-dev \
    autoconf \
    build-base \
    linux-headers \
    libaio-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    git \
    subversion \
    freetype-dev \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    bzip2-dev \
    libstdc++ \
    libxslt-dev \
    openldap-dev \
    hiredis-dev \
    make \
    unzip \
    ffmpeg \
    wget
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-imap --with-imap-ssl \
  && docker-php-ext-install -j 4 imap 


RUN docker-php-ext-install gd bcmath zip bz2 pdo pdo_mysql simplexml opcache sockets mbstring pcntl xsl pspell
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ 
RUN pecl install imagick
RUN docker-php-ext-enable imagick 
RUN pecl install xdebug
RUN wget http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.6.1.tgz
RUN tar -xvzf xdebug-2.6.1.tgz
RUN cd xdebug-2.6.1 \
    && phpize \
    && ./configure --enable-xdebug \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718 \
    && echo 'zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo 'zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so' >> /etc/php7/php.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=true' >> /etc/php7/php.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1' >> /etc/php7/php.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000' >> /etc/php7/php.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp' >> /etc/php7/php.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.max_nesting_level=512' >> /etc/php7/php.ini

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

RUN echo "Install ZeroMQ library and PHP extension"
RUN apk add --update autoconf gcc libzmq zeromq-dev zeromq coreutils build-base
RUN pecl install zmq-beta \
  && docker-php-ext-enable zmq
#COPY ./project /app
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
    php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
#RUN "composer install"


EXPOSE 80

EXPOSE 22
#CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
#CMD php artisan migrate --seed

CMD ["php-fpm"]
USER root
copy run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /run.sh  
RUN ls
#RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/run.sh"]
COPY ./././project app/
RUN composer install --no-dev --no-interaction -o

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

Comment: What's base image that used in your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I add Dockerfile to question list

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing PHP-FPM and a standalone PHP server.
Rather move the `artisan serve` to the CMD.
Also, you can only have one `CMD`, which is the command that needs to execute when the container starts. In order to execute other commands when building the container, you need to use the `RUN` command. So your Dockerfile can look like this:

```
WORKDIR '/app'
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
            php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

RUN "composer install"
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 22
CMD "php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80"
```

Comment: In your case I receive an error /bin/sh: composer install: not found
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c "composer install"' returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: Are you building the image, or trying to run an already built image? Your example is a Dockerfile that needs to be build into an image, but your command `docker run ... composer/composer` runs an existing image. So in order to use your config, you need to build the image first from the Dockerfile config

Comment: I build the image within this Dockerfile and in this Dockerfile I am trying to run composer install but receive an error.This is a php container.When I come in php container and run manualy composer install everything is fine/But not from dockerfile as I need

Comment: When the image is building, your project needs to be available in the container. So you need an `ADD ...` command that adds your project to the container, otherwise there is nothing to run the composer install against

Comment: When I trying to COPY I receive an errro COPY /var/www/docker/project /app
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder091462376/var/www/docker/project: no such file or directory

Comment: Can you try `COPY . /app` instead of using the full absolute path

Comment: I delete `RUN "composer install"` And change to `COPY . /app` There is no more error connecting with COPY but composer also didnt installed